# How to exclude something when output git log

Tags: git

I want to export log to csv by:

`git log -p --since='2 days ago' > log.csv`

How to exclude file like `.sql` or `.tpl`?

Answer (score 0):

```
git log -p --since='2 days ago' -- $(git ls-files | grep -v '*.sql')
```